# Add popup in action of ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

I have define a custom action in my model.Admin.

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['ID','Name']
    actions = ['show_report']
    def show_report(self,request,queryset):
          # Popup a form
          # User input message
          # finish, go back to changlist form and finish the action.
    show_report.short_description = "Show report for selected Project"
```

Then when i select one item in Project changelist form, there is a item "Show report", when user select and click the "Go" button, i want to popup a form which allows user to input some comment. For example, after user click this action, i want to popup a dialog to let user input some message and then click OK in the popup, then finish the action. Is there any way to implement this, Thanks.

**Update** Maybe there is a easy way to do this, in the admin there is a delete confirm page. So if i can integrate my action with that page can custom that page. I think i must be better. Who know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using intermediate page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages, but it's not popup.

EDIT:
Link update: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages

Comment: Yes, i think this is one method but after i finish the operation in the intermediate page, how can i go back to the current page and show the result of the action

Comment: I think, you can save referer url in session before redirect to intermediate page and then use it to return back.